# kernel panic hyper v vmbus

Tags: drivers, kernel, vmware, hyper-v

I found this error on Ubuntu VM hosted with Hyper-V.
Some help would be great.

Please see the attached picture.

[image: kernel panic vmbus]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Not very clear because just passed me the error and machine is not accesible, i have cloned machine and it boots, i think is a hw resource problem..as soon I get more info I will paste here, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Finally was solved changin network card in Hyper-V, seems to be affected if make some change in Hyper-V config.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by adding another core and more ram to the Virtual Machine, I was trying to install with 1 core and 1024mb ram. Added 2 vcores and 2048mb RAM, worked instantly.